# Please advise: Virtual machine has stopped working

Tags: solaris, central-processing-unit, vmware-player

We have a Solaris 10 machine that has just stopped working.

This is the error we get when we try to launch it:

[image]

Comment: You'll get down-voted because you're showing a lack of research into your own problem. I would start looking at the logs for VMware Player. You can also let everyone know what resources are assigned to this virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because of a Failure of a CPU.Try restarting the server instead of the VM.
The Memory allocated to the VM may be less and its trying to access more memory.

Comment: This answer is not particularly clear. Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is due to kernel panic.
it happens if you have installed new kernel, upgraded the drivers or softwares or changes kernel settings in Solaris.
reboot machine and check for problems in logs.